# Ola Hallengren Stored procs updated by windows patching?

Tags: ola-hallengren

we use OH maintenance solution on all of our SQL instances, no issues. On 01/23/2022, one of our SQL servers that is automatically patched with Windows patches went thru it's patching & rebooting cycle (like normal). Backups started failing with this error:
Procedure or function 'CommandExecute' expects parameter '@DatabaseContext', which was not supplied.
I see that both CommandExecute and IndexOptimize stored procedures were modified during the patching window. I know I have been using an older version of the maintenance solution (2018-06-20  on this instance, I think), but why would Windows patching apply new versions of Ola Hallengren stored procedures?
Thank you
Lori

Comment: Realistically Windows patching couldn't do this. Something else probably happened. Maybe you can get more details by comparing the closest backup you have prior to the Windows update to confirm it was already scripted the same way. This is a pretty abstract issue, so will be hard to debug without a lot more details.

Comment: If it helps, this is a CommVault instance. CommVault is saying they do update stored procs in the instance during updates, but cannot confirm they would update a 3rd party proc. Does that ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds like something you'll need to debug with your host, CommVault. They shouldn't be updating *any* procedures on your SQL Server for a Windows update, let alone user defined ones like Ola's scripts. Unless they're running custom software in your instance which would be very strange, but they still shouldn't be touching your user defined objects.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I agree 100%. I have determined that it was NOT windows updates that updated the proc, which leaves CommVault, and they cannot confirm or deny without looking at the DB, if it might have been their own software upgrade. I restored the previous version of the procs, and everything is back to normal.